# Rolling Johansen cointegration test in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels

I have a DataFrame with two price timeseries and I'd like to achieve a rolling Johansen cointegration of these series. I'm particularly interested in the eigenvalues from the result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm import coint_johansen

A = pd.Series(np.cumsum(np.random.normal(size=1000)) + 50, name='A')
B = pd.Series(A + 5 + np.random.normal(size=1000), name='B')

df = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)

res = coint_johansen(df, det_order=0, k_ar_diff=1)
res.eig
```

Is anybody able to show me how to turn this into a rolling series ?